# How do you find the longest sublist within a nested list

Tags: list-manipulation

Say, I have a list

```
stuff= {{eat, tea, now}, {how, did, you, say}, {the, cat, ate, was, can}, {win, din, sin}}
```

I have a nested list and I want to find the list that has the most words in it and then I want to find the length of those words.  How would I do that?

I thought it was

```
Max[StringLength[stuff]]
```

and

```
Length[Max[StringLength[stuff]]]
```

but `StringLength` doesn't do me any good here since the length of each letter is the same.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you want to find the sublist with the maximum length (i.e. most number of words), you don't need to concern yourself with `StringLength`. A simple solution would be to use `Pick` to select the longest list and then use `StringLength` to get the lengths.

```
With[{L = Length /@ stuff}, StringLength@Pick[stuff, L, Max@L]]
(* {{3, 3, 3, 3, 3}} *)
```

Comment: Would I also be able to use Select in this case?

Comment: Yes, you can use `Select`. Is there a reason you don't want to use `Pick`?

Comment: Because I have only used Pick for a simple set of lists, and not really familiar with it.  So, if you use Pick here, the program compares the lists, and "picks" the list with the highest amount of strings?

Comment: @thaibak527 Yes, it picks the sublists with the maximum length (because I told it to).

Comment: Great great, thank you I will remember that for future

Answer (score 1):

```
stuff={{eat, tea, now}, {how, did, you, say}, {the, cat, ate, was, can}, {win, din, sin}};

Composition[StringLength, Map[SymbolName], First, MaximalBy[Length]] @ stuff
```

> {3, 3, 3, 3, 3}

Comment: +1, though I think using `Map[SymolName]` might make it more slick.

Comment: @jjc385, great point; thank you. Updated with the version you suggested.